# JNA for a custom library

Tags: java, c++, jna

I am new to the JNA infrastructure but I think that the gist is that I have some library "someLib" and I create a java interface to match it.  Then I can 'just' use it right?

But the problem is that I am unsure of what I need to mock out, specifically there are some classes that I need the features of.

Lets say that my C++ lib has a 'AdvancedString' object - that internally uses some other classes.

Meaning it looks like this:

```
class B { ... };

class AdvancedString { 
  private: 
    B b;

  public:
    AdvancedString doSomething () { ... }

};
```

And I need to be able in the Java code to say AdvancedString.doSomething () and have it work.  This means that I need to...create an interface for the AdvancedString class?

```
public interface AdvancedStringInterface extends StdCallLibrary {
  public AdvancedStringInterface doSomething ();
}
```

Does that seem reasonable? Or am I missing something.  Thanks for any insight you can give!

Comment: JNA does not generally support C++ interfaces, only C.  So you'll likely need a C wrapper interface to use JNA.  (In particular, functions cannot be struct/class members in a C wrapper interface.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JNA will help you access C functions and data. One option is to expose your C++ functionality in a C API.

If you want to access many C++ classes, [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) is a better fit. It can create Java wrappers for your C++ classes. It is very powerful, but there is a learning curve.